# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

When I try to go to link `http://localhost:8080/` I get "HTTP Status 404", I use Tomcat 7.0.47, and I get the following error :  **The requested resource is not available.**

**WebConfig.Java**

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/views/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/views/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**WebAppInitalizer.Java**

```
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "config";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        System.out.println("***** Initializing Application for " + servletContext.getServerInfo() + " *****");

        // Create ApplicationContext
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);

        // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc-dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

**MainController.Java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String homepage(){
        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

My project has the following structure :

[image: The structure of my spring MVC project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` on top of `WebConfig` and change this `@ComponentScan` with this `@ComponentScan("controller")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some text into your `requestMapping` example:

```
@RequestMapping("/homePage")
```

and then go to http://localhost:8080/homePage